How to make qdisc permanent? (to persist reboots)
Related question is here but the answer is not very intuitive, surely there is more standard method to configure NIC:
How can I permanently associate tc qdisc commands with a particular interface?
Another related question is:
Can TC rules persist beyond a reboot? Where?
However I'm not using networking service to edit /etc/network/interfaces as detailed later in question.

Currently my wifi NIC is configured to use noqueue queuing discipline and I want to change it to fq_codel, but, so that it persists reboots:
ip link show dev wlan0
    
3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

To change qdisc I do:
sudo tc qdisc add dev wlan0 root fq_codel
ip link show dev wlan0

3: wlan0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:11:22:33:44:55 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff

This works, qdisc was changed as seen, but only until reboot.
I've also checked for default qdisc value set in system which is already set to fq_codel:
sudo sysctl net.core.default_qdisc

net.core.default_qdisc = fq_codel

Networking is controlled by systemd-networkd, networking service is disabled.
The NIC is managed by NetworkManager without any systemd config.

Rather than seeking to permanentize the setting, why not make settitng it part of system startup, or NIC startup? You'll be guaranteed the right setting whenever it (system or NIC) starts.

I figured out how to make the setting permanent without any startup scripts or extra configuration when using NetworkManager
First list connections:
nmcli connection

Sample output
NAME      UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE          
MyWifi  5120ec15-0c1e-4252-8f2e-905eb533be30    wifi      wlan0
... etc ...

Next from the listed connections from the output above which you want to modify qdisc,
(MyWifi in this case) issue the following command:
nmcli connection modify MyWifi tc.qdiscs 'root fq_codel'

That's it, reboot and the setting will persist.
